# Android. Как переопределить параметры часто используемого Toolbar

Tags: android, include, toolbar, атрибуты

Есть кастомный Toolbar, описанный в отдельном xml-файле. Необходимо при подключении его в других layout переопределить некоторые параметры, в зависимости от layout, как это сделать на уровне xml?

Пытался при подключении изменить текст, ничего не меняется, даже при отсутствии вышеуказанного в самом toolbar-layout

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_recoverypass"
        android:text = "forRegistration"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Comment: Слова "пытался.... ничего не получается" всегда должны сопровождаться кодом, которым пытался. А то, может, не получается, потому что пытался совсем не то.

Comment: Код, в котором "пытался", выше

Comment: это код, который "пытался при подключении изменить текст"?

Comment: `android:text` точно не будет менять текст на тулбаре, т.к. так можно только у TextView текст менять. Возможно, поможет вместо этого писать как-то так: `app:title`

Comment: Не помогло, но спасибо за замечание